# How is the sizing of buffered writes implemented in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase

HBase allows you to make the puts in batch mode. You can specify the batch size in terms of bytes. Whenever the underlying buffer is full, it is pushed to the server.

How does HBase calculate size of each put? Is there any way I can calculate the size of the Java object dynamically?  If so, could it be calculated cheaply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase uses a heuristic approximation of the sizes of `Put`s and `KeyValue`s to decide when to flush a buffered writer, as one can [see here](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.java#L672-L681).

The `heapSize()` method is brought in by the [`HeapSize`](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/HeapSize.java) interface, which [`KeyValue`](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.java#L1975-L1982) and [`Put`](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.java#L448-L475) both implement.

Notice in particular that `KeyValue` uses awareness of its own implementation to merely provide a reasonably accurate estimate of its own size.  There is no language-level magic for calculating the size precisely.

`KeyValue#heapSize` is a constant time algorithm.  `Put#heapSize` is linear in the number of contained `KeyValues`, and I would expect it to be fast enough for most purposes since individual puts often have fewer than a thousand cells.